# Interface implements F-Bounded interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm new to the F-Bounded interface concept.

I have a F-Bounded interface, A. I want to use it in the interface B. I only want to use generics on A, but if I don't use generics, B will throw warnings.
I'm looking for the best practice in this case. It would be nice to show also the implementation of B with the best solution.

```
public interface A<T extends A<T>>{
    T getSomething();
    void setSomething(T);
}
```

Here is the one i would like to use, but it obviously throws warnings.

```
public interface B{
    A getA();
    void setA();
}
```

This one works just fine, as long as they are few interfaces. As soon as I add more interfaces which i.e. using B, things get totally messy.

```
public interface B<T extends A<T>>{
    T getA();
    void setA(T);
}
```

Also, should I use the implementation of A in the interface B? This would eliminate the recurring generics, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: What is `F` in `F-Bounded`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not really sure myself, but it's another name for recursive bounding, or something like that (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)). Not really sure about alternative names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an unbounded wildcard.

```
public interface B{
    A<?> getA();
    void setA(A<?> a);
}
```